# Private values in OCaml module?

Tags: module, ocaml, private

Is is possible to have a `let` binding (whether a function, value etc.) that is **private** to its module, and not visible from outside?

Let's say we have `A.ml`:

```ml
let exported = 1
let local = 2
```

I only want `exported` to be accessible from other modules. `B.ml`:

```ml
let a = A.exported
let error = A.local (* This should error *)
```

Similar to what `let%private` does in *Reason*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't idiomatic, but for completion's sake:

Since [4.08](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.08.0), when `open` was extended to accept arbitrary module expressions, it's possible to create private bindings without using module signatures:

```
open struct
  let local = 2
end
```

Before this you'd have to give the module a name and then open it, which will expose the module with its contents, although it can of course be given a name that suggests it shouldn't be used.

```
module Internal = struct
  let local = 2
end

open Internal
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the motivation behind signature and mli files: they allow to hide information to the external world and expose only the relevant part of your API and not implementation details. In your case, it would look like

```
(* A.ml *)
let exported = 1
let local = 2
```

and

```
(* A.mli *)
val exported: int
```

Then only `exported` will be visible outside of `A.ml`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's what [module signatures](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/moduleexamples.html#s%3Asignature) and on the file level [the .mli file](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/moduleexamples.html#s%3Aseparate-compilation) is for.

Briefly explained, add an `A.mli`, then put the definitions you want to export into it:

```ml
val exported : int
```